# HTML5 Canvas Drawing GetContext("2d") - Null is not an object (variable.getContext)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When attempting to create an HTML5 Canvas clock from a tutorial on Youtube. I followed the instructions and all through the demo, I was not able to view my clock on my own browsers (Safari 8.0.7 and FireFox 39.0.3), it displays a blank screen - like there is no code there. After looking in the developer menu (Inspect Element) in Safari, I was informed of this error message with my JavaScript code:

---

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'myVariable.getContext')

---

After seeing this, I decided to place message box "breakpoints" to discover where the code stopped executing. I learned using that method that it was indeed in relation to the getContext("2d") method.

I would like to take this opportunity to share my code with you. Please note that there is a loop to be able to refresh this clock every 40 milliseconds in order to get a smooth motion from the seconds clock.

Here is my code:

```js
window.alert("1");
/*Status -- Worked*/
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
window.alert("2");
/*Status -- Worked*/
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
window.alert("3");
/*Status -- Failed to show in Safari*/

ctx.strokeStyle = "28d1fa";
ctx.lineWidth = 17;
ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
ctx.shadowColor = "28d1fa";

function degToRad(degree) {
  "use strict";
  var factor = Math.PI / 180;
  return degree * factor;
}

function renderTime() {
  //Variables
  "use strict";
  var now = new Date();
  var today = now.toDateString();
  var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  var milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
  var newSeconds = seconds * (milliseconds / 1000);

  //Background
  gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(250, 250, 5, 250, 250, 300);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, "09303a");
  gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillStyle = "333333";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  //Hours
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 200, degToRad(270), degToRad((hours * 15) - 90));
  ctx.stroke();

  //Minutes
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 170, degToRad(270), degToRad((minutes * 6) - 90));
  ctx.stroke();

  //Seconds
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 140, degToRad(270), degToRad((newSeconds * 6) - 90));
  ctx.stroke();

  //Date
  ctx.font = "25px Arial bold";
  ctx.fillStyle = "28d1fa";
  ctx.fillText(today, 175, 250);

  //Time
  ctx.font = "15px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "28d1fa";
  ctx.fillText(time, 175, 280);


}

setInterval(renderTime, 40);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</body>

</html>
```

At your earliest convenience, could you assist me in solving this issue?

It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Sincerely,

Coder 206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading the JavaScript before the canvas is loaded, because the `<script>` tag is higher up the page.

Load the JavaScript after the canvas and `document.getElementById("canvas");` will not be `null` as the canvas will have been loaded onto the page already.

```
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wait for the page to load before trying to execute your javascript.

So wrap your javascript code inside:

```
window.onload=function(){

    ... your code ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Robin James Kerrison and markE.

To: Robin James Kerrison

Thank you so much for the clarification! This will help me in the future!

To: markE

Thank you for your help, this is my backup when things go wrong ;)

To: Everyone

This is my code in proper working order thanks to the great Stack Overflow users mentioned above.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = "28d1fa";
ctx.lineWidth = 17;
ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
ctx.shadowColor = "28d1fa";

function degToRad(degree) {
  var factor = Math.PI / 180;
  return degree * factor;
}

function renderTime() {
  //Variables
  var now = new Date();
  var today = now.toDateString();
  var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var seconds = now.getSeconds();
  var milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
  var newSeconds = seconds + (milliseconds / 1000);

  //Background
  var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(250, 250, 5, 250, 250, 300);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, "09303a");
      gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");
  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  ctx.fillStyle = "333333";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  //Hours
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 200, degToRad(270), degToRad((hours * 15) - 90));
  ctx.stroke();

  //Minutes
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 170, degToRad(270), degToRad((minutes * 6) - 90));
  ctx.stroke();

  //Seconds
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(250, 250, 140, degToRad(270), degToRad((newSeconds * 6) - 90));
  ctx.stroke();

  //Date
  ctx.font = "25px Arial bold";
  ctx.fillStyle = "28d1fa";
  ctx.fillText(today, 175, 250);

  //Time
  ctx.font = "15px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "28d1fa";
  ctx.fillText(time, 175, 280);


}

setInterval(renderTime, 40);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project</title>
        <link rel=""
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <script src="script/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```